# How can I use a jQuery string as an object name?

Tags: jquery, string, function, object

How can I use a string variable as an object name in jQuery?

`var elem = "objectName";`

...to be used in a similar fashion to...

`var opts = $.nt.elem.options;`

I tried `var opts = $.nt[elem]options;` to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed a dot in `var opts = $.nt[elem].options;`

Comment: Ah. Good catch. I tried dots on both sides, but not just on the right. Thank you!